# How to split a number into 12 random in python and all random number sum to be equal to the number

Tags: python

Hello guys i have a problem that that contain any number (eg- 167) will be split into 12 random numbers the sum of the 12 random numbers should be the original number And the numbers be positive, larger than zero, integers

for this i have written a code :

```
a = 167
n = 12
out = diff([0,sort(randperm(a-1,n-1)),a])
```

here i'm getting a error

> name 'diff' is not defined

Another way:

```
a =  50390
b = rand(10,1)
b  = b/sum(b)*a
out=round(b)
out(1) = out(1) - (a-sum(out))
```

Note: this both code is not working so please tell me how to do it

please help me get it..thanks

Comment: What do you think is `diff`? What is it supposed to do? As a side note, there are no semicolons in Python.

Comment: @DYZ There are semicolons in python, just not used in this example. They allow several python statements on the same line.

Comment: srry for  that i know it but anyway its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it.

```
from random import randint
a = 167
n = 12

assert a >= n >= 1

pieces = []
for idx in range(n-1):
    # Number between 1 and a
    # minus the current total so we don't overshoot
    # minus 1 for each number that hasn't been picked
    # so they can all be nonzero
    pieces.append(randint(1,a-sum(pieces)-n+idx))
pieces.append(a-sum(pieces))
```

Note that these numbers aren't independent; any time you add a constraint like `THE n VALUES MUST TOTAL a`, you're taking away some of the randomness. Here, the numbers later in the distribution are likely to be smaller than the earlier numbers, until the last number which is expected to be average again. If you don't like that trend, you can `shuffle()` the resultant list, `pieces`.

Edit: For floats, you don't have to save space for the next value (ditto for non-negative int instead of positive int), so it'd look a little different. Basically, you just remove the `-n+idx` term from the expression, since you no longer need to allocate `n-idx` more pieces >=1.

```
from random import uniform
a = 166.667
n = 12

assert a > 0
assert n >= 1

pieces = []
for idx in range(n-1):
    # Number between 0 and a
    # minus the current total so we don't overshoot
    pieces.append(uniform(0,a-sum(pieces)))
pieces.append(a-sum(pieces))
```

Comment: sir Thanks for the code its really good but i have one doubt if we have float(a=166.667) value in place of interger (i,e a=167) then how we can do it?

Comment: Added code to the original solution; hope it adds some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
def num_pieces(num,lenght):
    ot = list(range(1,lenght+1))[::-1]
    all_list = []
    for i in range(lenght-1):
        n = random.randint(1, num-ot[i])
        all_list.append(n)
        num -= n
    all_list.append(num) 
    return all_list

num_pieces(167,12)
```